# RHEL 6 - 64 bit with 32 bit Libraries from JDK

Tags: java-6, rhel6

I have a Linux Redhat 6 with 64 bit installed and working well with some application.

My problem is i tried to install jdk1.6u30 32bit edition because i need it.

i also installed the glibc.i686, glibc-devel.i686 and compat-libstdc++, ...

each time i have the following error :

```
/sbin/ldconfig: libraries libselinux.so and libselinux.so.1 in directory /lib have same soname but different type.
/sbin/ldconfig: libraries libcidn.so.1 and libcidn.so in directory /lib have same soname but different type.
/sbin/ldconfig: libraries libm.so.6 and libm.so in directory /lib have same soname but different type.
/sbin/ldconfig: libraries libanl-2.12.so and libanl.so in directory /lib have same soname but different type.
/sbin/ldconfig: libraries libdb-4.7.so and libdb.so in directory /lib have same soname but different type.
/sbin/ldconfig: libraries libutil-2.12.so and libutil.so in directory /lib have same soname but different type.
/sbin/ldconfig: libraries libcrypt.so.1 and libcrypt.so in directory /lib have same soname but different type.
/sbin/ldconfig: libraries libgssrpc.so and libgssrpc.so.4.1 in directory /lib have same soname but different type.
/sbin/ldconfig: libraries libcom_err.so.2 and libcom_err.so in directory /lib have same soname but different type.
/sbin/ldconfig: libraries libkeyutils.so.1 and libkeyutils.so in directory /lib have same soname but different type.
/sbin/ldconfig: libraries libdl-2.12.so and libdl.so in directory /lib have same soname but different type.
/sbin/ldconfig: libraries libthread_db-1.0.so and libthread_db.so in directory /lib have same soname but different type.
/sbin/ldconfig: libraries libgssapi_krb5.so.2 and libgssapi_krb5.so in directory /lib have same soname but different type.
/sbin/ldconfig: libraries libnss_nisplus-2.12.so and libnss_nisplus.so in directory /lib have same soname but different type.
/sbin/ldconfig: libraries libBrokenLocale.so.1 and libBrokenLocale.so in directory /lib have same soname but different type.
/sbin/ldconfig: libraries libkrb5support.so.0 and libkrb5support.so in directory /lib have same soname but different type.
/sbin/ldconfig: libraries libnss_hesiod-2.12.so and libnss_hesiod.so in directory /lib have same soname but different type.
/sbin/ldconfig: libraries libaudit.so and libaudit.so.1.0.0 in directory /lib have same soname but different type.
/sbin/ldconfig: libraries libnsl-2.12.so and libnsl.so in directory /lib have same soname but different type.
/sbin/ldconfig: libraries libnss_compat-2.12.so and libnss_compat.so in directory /lib have same soname but different type.
/sbin/ldconfig: libraries libpamc.so and libpamc.so.0.82.1 in directory /lib have same soname but different type.
/sbin/ldconfig: libraries librt.so.1 and librt.so in directory /lib have same soname but different type.
/sbin/ldconfig: libraries libnss_dns.so.2 and libnss_dns.so in directory /lib have same soname but different type.
/sbin/ldconfig: /lib/libgettextlib-0.17.so is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig: /lib/libdb_cxx-4.7.so is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig: /lib/libdb-4.7.so is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig: /lib/libgettextsrc-0.17.so is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig: libraries libkdb5.so and libkdb5.so.4.0 in directory /usr/lib have same soname but different type.
/sbin/ldconfig: /usr/lib/libgettextlib-0.17.so is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig: /usr/lib/libdb_cxx-4.7.so is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig: /usr/lib/libgettextsrc-0.17.so is not a symbolic link

Installing : glibc-devel-2.12-1.7.el6.i686 2/2

Installed:
glibc.i686 0:2.12-1.7.el6 glibc-devel.i686 0:2.12-1.7.el6
```

And then the java doesn't work

I checked up the libraries needed in the /lib, but it seems like there are the same that the one's in /lib64.

Any ideas.